# Ruby on Rails equivalent to actionscript

Tags: ruby, actionscript, ruby-on-rails-4

i have the below actionscript and looking for the equivalent ruby on rails code to do the same job.

where dbwall and db_wall = 50

```
var tb= Math.pow((1/10),(dbwall)/(10));
```

Currently i have used:

```
@tb = ((1/10) ** (db_wall)/10)
```

and get 0.0, which is not what i need:
however in actionscript the actual answer to this is 0.00001

Is it just a case of the correct formula but not showing decimal places? or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer division in Ruby returns an integer (like C) so `1/10` equals `0`. To get Float division, explicitly make one of the operands a Float e.g. `1.0/10`

Comment: ok, so altered to @tb = ((1.0/10) ** (wall_db/10)), this gives 1.0000000000000003e-05 ?

Comment: That is scientific notation for 0.000010000000000000003 which is as close to your desired answer as you can hope when floats are involved.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include a few of the brackets too.

```
@tb = ((1/10) ** db_wall/10)
```

Would simply work. I wouldn't make this variable accessible to the view by using @ if you carry on, just take that off and use it in future calculations.

What Max has answered would be the best answer to this simple problem.